# MS Access 2010 - MsgBox to Run Query & Delete Record Not Working

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a button on a Continuous subform with the below VBA attached -

```
Private Sub del_Click()
On Error GoTo del_Click_Err
Dim LResponse As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToControl Screen.PreviousControl.Name
    Err.Clear

    If (Not Form.NewRecord) Then
        LResponse = Eval("MsgBox('You are about to delete a record.'" & _
                    "'@If you click yes, you won't be able to undo this delete operation.' & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " & _
                    "'Are you sure you want to delete this record?@@', 276, 'Are you sure?')")
        If LResponse = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_DeleteSpecific"
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Else
        End If
    End If

    If (Form.NewRecord And Not Form.Dirty) Then
        Beep
    End If

    If (Form.NewRecord And Form.Dirty) Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    End If

    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

del_Click_Exit:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

del_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume del_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

The button was originally the auto-generated 'Delete Record' button and I have since modified it to include the query activation as well as my own msgBox.

The 'delete' button obviously worked fine before modification.  The query also works as intended and I tested a button on a seperate form that just included the MsgBox code, which also worked.

But bringing it all together has failed somehow.  When I click the button I don't get the MsgBox and it doesn't delete a record or run the query.

```
DoCmd.GoToControl Screen.PreviousControl.Name
```

This line appears to have fired correctly though.

Could anybody explain what may be going wrong with this?

**---Edit---**

Replaced

```
Error Clear
```

With

```
On Error GoTo del_Click_Err
```

I now get the error message -

> The expression you entered contains invalid syntax

Comment: Where you have `Err.Clear` you should have `On Error GoTo del_Click_Err`, otherwise all your code will ignore errors, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Thankyou @Andre see above edit

Comment: While debugging, `On Error Goto 0` is sometimes the best option, it will stop the code and highlight the offending line. With the generic `On Error Goto Handler` one doesn't know where the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out it was all in the Quotes.  The quotation issue is still a bit of a mystery to me, but I managed to get my code working.

Here's the change -

```
LResponse = Eval("MsgBox(""You are about to delete a record."" & " & _
            """@If you click yes, you won't be able to undo this delete operation."" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " & _
            """Are you sure you want to delete this record?@@"", 276, ""Are you sure?"")")
```

Single quotes seemed to work when it was just the msgBox code by itself but not in the extended code.  Anyway, I'll know to look out for this again.

@Andre your comment helped me debug this.  I initially left 'Error Clear' as that was what the wizard put in for the delete button.

Comment: See here for a better readable implementation of the formatted MsgBox than doing it all inline in your code: http://access.mvps.org/access/bugs/bugs0035.htm